# Maven and Docker Builds, Releases and Deploy on Kubernetes/OpenShift

Tags: git, maven, docker, kubernetes, openshift

I'm struggling with the conception of a sensible tagging/naming convention for my project. I would definitely like to use semantic versioning, i.e. tagging the production image as **x.y.z**, where **x** is the **major**, **y** is the **minor** and **z** is the **patch** version.

Overall, I have three stages: **DEV**, **QA** and **PROD**. The process is as follows:

1. A commit is pushed to a remote **feature/patch branch**, which is branched from **master**
2. The **build verifier** is started and runs several tests
3. A **code review** is done by another developer
4. The branch is **merged** into master
5. The **build pipeline** is started and a maven and a docker image is built
6. The docker image is **deployed to DEV**
7. The image, which runs flawlessly on DEV is **deployed to QA**
8. If QA approves, the image is **deployed to PROD**.

What I need now is a strategy, how I can achieve a semantic versioning with labels. Initially our **Maven pom** has the version **1.0.0-SNAPSHOT** and the maven-docker-plugin replaces that with the label **latest** before tagging the Docker image. What I would like for my first **PROD image** is the tag **1.0.0**. What is the suggestion for the version number of the **QA image**? **1.0.0-RC**? I guess, it would be best, if I build the the image only once - before deploying to DEV - and subsequently only tag and deploy it to the remaining two stages?

Overall: is or should there be a difference in versioning between the **Maven** and the **Docker** image?

Thanks in advance!